# LARAVEL 6.x = Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I wish to be able to edit my users through the admin panel but this returns the following error to me:

Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

it will be an error in my view with the call of the variable ID if I change it I have the same thing with my variable name.

I use the users table and in no other place in my code do I have problems

help me please

URI : /role-edit/{id}

```
View : 

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">

                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h4>Edit register roles</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                            <form action="/role-register-update/{{ $users->id }}" method="POST">
                                {{ csrf_field() }}
                                {{ method_field('PUT') }}

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ $users->name }}" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Give role</label>
                                    <select name="type" class="form-control">
                                        <option value="admin">Admin</option>
                                        <option value="vendor">Vendor</option>
                                        <option value="">None</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
                                    <a href="/role-register" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</a>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



Controller :

class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function registered()
    {
        $users = User::all();
        return view('admin.registeradmin')->with('users', $users);
    }

    public function edit(Request $request,$id)
    {
        $users = User::findOrFail($id);
        return view('admin.edit-register')->with('users',$users);
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $users = User::findOrFail($id);

        $users->name = $request->input('name');
        $users->usertype = $request->input('type');
        $users->update();

        return redirect('/role-register')->with('status', 'You data is update');
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $users = User::where('id', $id);

        if ($users != null)
        {
            $users->delete();
            return redirect('/role-register')->with('status', 'User is correctly deleted !');
        }
        return redirect('/role-register')->with('status', 'User is not correctly deleted !');
    }


}


Routes :

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('pages.home');
});

Route::get('/aboutus', function () {
    return view('pages.aboutus');
})->name('aboutus');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('profile', 'UserProfileController@show')->middleware('auth')->name('profile.show');
Route::post('profile', 'UserProfileController@update')->middleware('auth')->name('profile.update');

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'admin']], function () {

    Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
        return view('admin.dashboard');
    });

    Route::get('/role-register', 'Admin\DashboardController@registered');

    Route::get('/role-edit/{id}', 'Admin\DashboardController@edit');

    Route::put('/role-register-update/{id}', 'Admin\DashboardController@update');

    Route::delete('/role-delete/{id}', 'Admin\DashboardController@destroy');

});
```

Comment: Please can you show the controller method that returns the view.

Comment: public function edit(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $users = User::findOrFail($id);
        return view('admin.edit-register')->with('users',$users);
    }

Comment: The code you've provided doesn't look like it should cause the error. The error `Trying to get 'id' of non-object` is essentially just saying you've used ->id` on something that is not an object (`->` is used to access properties or call methods on an object). Some usually suspects for this are either a variable is `null` or it's an array, but it could be something else. Does the error give you anymore information i.e. the file (and possibly line) that is causing the error and/or a stack trace? Also, does this happen before or after you submit the form?

Comment: Yes the error give me line and file and it's in my view on this two line :
<form action="/role-register-update/{{ $users->id }}" method="POST">

<input type="text" name="name" value="{{ $users->name }}" class="form-control">

Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/projetS/resources/views/admin/edit-register.blade.php)

Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleError
:18
resources/views/admin/edit-register.blade.php:18

Comment: My error will come from {{$ users-> id}} but in my controller I declare the variable and I call it in the view I do not understand or do I do another error

Comment: Like I said, from the code you've provided you shouldn't be getting the error. I would check to see if you're overriding the `$users` variable somewhere else. Trying changing `$users` to `$user` in both your `edit()` method and blade file. If that doesn't work please may you show your routes and the uri you're using to access the page.

Comment: when I changed it, I had this message :

Undefined variable: user (View: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/projetS/resources/views/admin/edit-register.blade.php)

Comment: In that case please can you show all the code for your controller, all the routes for that controller and the `uri` you going to in the browser.

Comment: My controller : https://codeshare.io/2jV3qB

My Routes : https://codeshare.io/503YmL

My view :  https://codeshare.io/24Lzyb

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for adding the rest of your view and the routes, however, I would always recommend just adding the code straight into your question rather than linked to a external site. The link you provided for your controller code showed your view instead so please can you edit your question and add all the code for your `DashboardController`. Lastly, please can you show **the uri you're going to in the browser** where the error is occurring (It doesn't need to include the domain).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
// Controller 
 public function Updateprofile(Request $request)
    {
        if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role->id == 2) {

            $this->validate($request, [
                'name' => 'required',
                'email' => 'required|email'
            ]);

            $image = $request->file('image');
            $slug = str_slug($request->name);
            if (isset($image))
            {
                $currentDate = Carbon::now()->toDateString();
                $imagename = $slug.'-'.$currentDate.'-'. uniqid() .'.'. $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $image_resize = Image::make($image->getRealPath());
                $image_resize->resize(600,500);
                if (!file_exists('storage/uploads/profile'))
                {
                    mkdir('storage/uploads/profile',0777,true);
                }
                unlink('storage/uploads/profile/'.Auth::user()->image);
                $image_resize->save('storage/uploads/profile/'.$imagename);
            }else{
                $imagename = Auth::user()->image;
            }
            $user = User::find(Auth::id());
            $user->name = $request->name;
            $user->email = $request->email;
            $user->image = $imagename;
            $user->save();
            Toastr::success('Profile Successfully Updated :)', 'Success');
            return redirect()->back();
        }

    }

// blade file

<form method="POST" action="{{route('user.profile.update')}}" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 @csrf
 @method('PUT')
    <div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-5 form-control-label">
        <label for="name">Name : </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-8 col-xs-7">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-line">
                <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your name" name="name" value="{{Auth::user()->name}} {{old('name')}}">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-5 form-control-label">
        <label for="image">{{__('Image')}} : </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-8 col-xs-7">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-line">
                <input  type="file"  name="image" >
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-5 form-control-label">
        <label for="email_address_2">Email Address</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-8 col-xs-7">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-line">
                <input type="text" id="email_address_2" class="form-control" value="{{Auth::user()->email}} {{old('email')}}" placeholder="Enter your email address" name="email" ">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-4 col-xs-offset-5">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary m-t-15 waves-effect">UPDATE</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Add `dd($users)` in the edit function of your controller. If you get the data, add the following to the form action form action:

```
{{route('routename',['id'=>$users->id])}}
```

Comment: I don't have any date when I using dd on my $users

Comment: Then id is not passed to edit function in your controller.How you redirect to role-edit/{id} url.Can you show that as well?