# Laravel 6.x : Update method in UserController

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

Hello everyone I allow myself to come to you because I am faced with a problem indeed when I want to implement the update method in my user controller it does not work I explain two. When I go to my edition view of wrestling games, my data is good but when I modify it and send it nothing happens I just come back to a page with a message telling me that my data is up to date in my table no update data I join my controller saw me and my routes

Controller :

```php
public function update(Request $request, User $user)
{
    // $user = User::findOrFail($id);

    $request->validate([
        'firstname' => 'required',
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'usertype' => 'required',
    ]);

    $user->update($request->all());

    return redirect('/role-register')->with('status', 'The account is update !');
}
```

Edit view :

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">

                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h4>Edit register roles</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">

                            <form action="{{ route('role.update', ['id', $users->id]) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
                                @csrf
                            @method('PUT')
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>First Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="{{ $users->firstname }}" class="form-control">
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ $users->name }}" class="form-control">
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Email</label>
                                    <input type="email" name="email" value="{{ $users->email }}" class="form-control">
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Give role</label>
                                    <select name="usertype" class="form-control" value="{{ $users->usertype }}">
                                        <option value="admin">Admin</option>
                                        <option value="user">user</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
                                    <a href="{{ route('role.register') }}" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</a>
                                </div>
                            </form>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Route :

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'admin']], function () {

    Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
        return view('admin.dashboard');
    })->name('dashboard');

    Route::get('/role-register', 'Admin\DashboardController@registered')->name('role.register');

    Route::get('/role-edit/{id}', 'Admin\DashboardController@edit')->name('role.edit');

    Route::put('/role-register-update/{id}', 'Admin\DashboardController@update')->name('role.update');

    Route::delete('/role-delete/{id}', 'Admin\DashboardController@destroy')->name('role.delete');

    Route::get('/cutomers', function () {
        return view('admin.customer');
    })->name('customers.list');
});
```

Thx for helping me

Comment: first check `dd($request->all())` ? check you getting all form data ??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59797212/11215386
//follow this link. i

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that those inputs added to `$fillable` in your `User.php` Model

```php
class User extends Authenticatable
{
   ...
   protected $fillable = [
     'firstname' => 'required',
     'name' => 'required',
     'email' => 'required',
     'usertype' => 'required',
   ];
....
```

Try this in your controller and let me know what happens:

```php
...
   $updated = $user->update($request->all());
   if($updated){
    return redirect('/role-register')->with('status', 'The account is update !');
   }else{
       return redirect('/role-register')->with('status', 'Could not update');
   }
```

#### In your web.php file update from

`Route::put('/role-register-update/{id}`

#### To

`Route::put('/role-register-update/{user}`

#### Or change the controller's method from

`...Request $request, User $user){...`

#### To

`...Request $request, User $id){...`

Comment: Hi, its verified and this is same as you :(

Comment: you get that it's Updated because you have it coded to say so 
` return redirect('/role-register')->with('status', 'The account is update !');`

Comment: ...
   $updated = $user->update($request->all());
   if($updated){
    return redirect('/role-register')->with('status', 'The account is update !');
   }else{
       return redirect('/role-register')->with('status', 'Could not update');
   }

Comment: yes but now you should be getting "Could not update" right?

Comment: what do you get instead?

Comment: can you update your question and show us the whole update method in your controller `public function update(....`

Comment: you used `{id}` in your web, but you need to replace that with `{user}`

Answer (score 0):

when you using **model binding** you have to use same word in route

```
Route::put('/role-register-update/{user}', 'Admin\DashboardController@update')->name('role.update');

public function update(Request $request, User $user)
{
    .....
    $user->update($request->all());

    return redirect('/role-register')->with('status', 'The account is update !');
}

<form action="{{ route('role.update', ['user', $users->id]) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
```

else

```
Route::put('/role-register-update/{id}', 'Admin\DashboardController@update')->name('role.update');

    public function update(Request $request,$id)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);
        .....
        $user->update($request->all());

        return redirect('/role-register')->with('status', 'The account is update !');
    }
```

Comment: When I using your method and I click on update I have an error like it : Call to a member function update() on null

But it's not null because i have users

Comment: first or second ? what is your PK in user table ?

Comment: My PK ? what is it ?

Comment: Primary key ? if your Pk is different from name id then you have to define your PK in your model `protected $primaryKey = 'your_user_pk';`

Comment: My PK is my id on my user table

Comment: My edit function 

    $users = User::where('id', $id)->first();
    if ($id != null)
    {
    return view('admin.edit-register', ['users' => $users]);
    }
    return redirect('/role-register')->with('status', 'Your data is update');

Comment: use my first method and change in your form also `['user', $users->id]`

Comment: Where I put this change in my form ?

Comment: in your update function check check `dd($user,$request->all())` you getting both or $user is null ??